Systemctl service error permission denied while using root and granting all permissions
I have a Golang application which already compiled on local and pushed to production server, but when I tried to set it up with systemd service it keeps getting permission denied error, even though I'm using root user and is the owner of the whole application folder and subfolders.
My application is on folder path "/home/my-user/app/src/my-app-api" which consists of the compiled app "my_api" (unix executable file) and an .env.
/etc/systemd/system/my_api.service
[Unit]
Description=APP API
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
ExecStart=/home/my-user/app/src/my-app-api/my_api
WorkingDirectory=/home/my-user/app/src/my-app-api
EnvironmentFile=/home/my-user/app/src/my-app-api/.env

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

when I ran "sudo systemctl start my_api.service" it always returns this error in "systemctl status my_api.service"
May 17 06:07:57 websitename systemd[1]: my_api.service: Failed to load environment files: Permission denied
May 17 06:07:57 websitename systemd[1]: my_api.service: Failed to run 'start' task: Permission denied
May 17 06:07:57 websitename systemd[1]: my_api.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
May 17 06:07:57 websitename systemd[1]: Failed to start APP API.

I have used chmod 777 -R to the app folder and contents and .env and the my_api.service file. Tried using sudo or non sudo, with root user or other user, folder and files belong to user root and group root, but still experiencing this error. What is possibly causing this and how to fix this? Thank you in advance.

I bet you a stone against a burger that it is SELinux. That being said: You evidently have little clue when it comes to security (making a root owned file both writable and executable by literally every other user is a Very Bad Idea™ ), so please read up and make sure you understand permissions and SELinux properly before any further steps. "I just want it to work" in a security context may lead to actions that can cause severe harm.

Hi @MarkusWMahlberg you are definitely correct 100%, and it solved this, thanks a lot, if you would put your comment as an answer I will accept it as the answer. Thanks

The issue here, as stated by the original poster, was a problem with SELinux permissions.
I ran into the problem myself due to using SCP to copy a file from one server to another with the destination being my home directory. After that I had moved the file over to it's proper location on the server but it retained a user_home_t context which I hadn't realized until reading Markus's comment and running ls with the -Z flag so that I could see the SELinux permissions. In my case I was able to run a command such as sudo chcon -R -t unlabeled_t /myfile.file in order to set things right.
Hopefully this information in a form of an answer will help anybody else who runs into this or a similar problem troubleshooting SELinux. Credit goes to Markus who originally posted the suggestions in the comment on the original question.
References:

RedHat SELinux - Top Three Causes of Problems

